# Django include url configuration

Tags: django

I have the following url patterns in ROOT_URLCONF:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My question is how the include works. What is the difference between `'polls.urls'` and `polls.urls`. The first one works and brings in the polls.urls.py file.

What does the include actually do? Can I be pointed to documentation? (When I google search for include, I only find out about template includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is a string and the other is an object reference. You can't reference objects whose names aren't known.

```
import polls.urls
```

["Including other URLconfs"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)